# How to queue an event before releasing it to those bound to it

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have an event that is scattered throughout my program. Whenever we make a change that is committed to the database, we fire off a ModelChanged event that includes arbitrary information, which is then picked up by a variety of GUI elements to update the screen. However, I'm doing a bit of refactoring on how this is working. Instead of the GUI elements capturing the event as soon as it's fired, I wish to pause it until another event happens. So, instead of doing this:

Fire Event -> Bindings receive event

I want it to do this:

Fire Event -> Wait for another separate event to fire -> Bindings receive original event.

Here is some code:

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select(['3.0', '2.8'])
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent

OriginalEvent, ORIGINAL_EVT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
ReleaseEvent, RELEASE_EVT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.fireOriginalBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Fire Event")
        self.fireOriginalBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.fireOriginal)

        self.releaseEventBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Release Event")
        self.releaseEventBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.releaseEvent)

        self.sizer.Add(self.fireOriginalBtn, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.releaseEventBtn, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)

        self.Bind(ORIGINAL_EVT, self.captureOriginal)
        self.Bind(RELEASE_EVT, self.captureRelease)
        self.Show(True)

    def fireOriginal(self, evt):
        wx.PostEvent(self, OriginalEvent(myInfo=[1,2,3,4]))

    def releaseEvent(self, evt):
        wx.PostEvent(self, ReleaseEvent())

    def captureOriginal(self, evt):
        print "Event captured"

    def captureRelease(self, evt):
        print "Release captured"

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Small editor')
app.MainLoop()
```

Currently, when you click Fire Event, you'll get text printed to the console. I want to be able to click the "Fire Event" button, but wait until I click the "Release Event" button before my frame gets the original event and prints to console.

I don't know enough about how to write my own event classes - maybe there's some things I can override to tell it when to emit the event or not, and a cursory look didn't get anywhere. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this something that you could use `wx.EVT_IDLE` instead?

Comment: No, not really - https://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.IdleEvent-class.html

Answer (score 0):

wxPython is event driven like every other GUI toolkit. There is no method to make an event pause and wait for a second event. Instead you can just set a property that tells you when the Fire Event button was pressed and use that property in the second event to determine what you should do. Here's an example:

```
import wxversion
wxversion.select(['3.0', '2.8'])
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent

OriginalEvent, ORIGINAL_EVT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
ReleaseEvent, RELEASE_EVT = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200,100))
        self.fire_event = False

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.fireOriginalBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Fire Event")
        self.fireOriginalBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.fireOriginal)

        self.releaseEventBtn = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Release Event")
        self.releaseEventBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.releaseEvent)

        self.sizer.Add(self.fireOriginalBtn, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(self.releaseEventBtn, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.SetAutoLayout(1)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)

        self.Bind(ORIGINAL_EVT, self.captureOriginal)
        self.Bind(RELEASE_EVT, self.captureRelease)
        self.Show(True)

    def fireOriginal(self, evt):
        self.fire_event = True

    def releaseEvent(self, evt):
        wx.PostEvent(self, ReleaseEvent())
        if self.fire_event:
            wx.PostEvent(self, OriginalEvent(myInfo=[1,2,3,4]))
            self.fire_event = False

    def captureOriginal(self, evt):
        print "Event captured"

    def captureRelease(self, evt):
        print "Release captured"

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MyFrame(None, 'Small editor')
app.MainLoop()
```